# Why my site loads too Slow?

Tags: plugins, blog

One of my site https://www.coinsqna.com loads very slow but the other site i host on the same server with same theme/plugins loads fast.

I don't know why, i use 
w3total cache plugin
Fast Velocity Minify
Yoast
Jetpack
DW Questions Answers pro
Accelerated Mobile Pages
Advanced Ads for AMP
Thirsty Affiliates

Can anyone please let me know if there's any changes i need to make from my end.

Answer (score 1):

try to minimize the number of plugins... you have used so many have plugins that's why it's loading slow...
as i can see following are the issues causing your website to load slow..
1) https://ichnaea.netflix.com/log net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID - monet.min.js

2) or you can check in google pagespeed test to check which are the things causing your website to load slow... you can increase pagespeed ranking by doing the things which google is suggesting  for your website..

Direct link to pagespeed for your website :
[a link] https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.coinsqna.com&tab=desktop [/a link]

give upvote if this answer helpful for you..